# Spring boot ComponentScan excludeFIlters not excluding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am having a **SimpleTest** :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SimpleTestConfig.class)
public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertThat(true);
    }
}
```

and a **configuration** for this test :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {
        SimpleTestConfig.class,
        Application.class
},
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                classes = Starter.class))
public class SimpleTestConfig {
}
```

I am trying to exclude the **Starter** class

```
package application.starters;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class Starter {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("initializing");
    }
}
```

And the **Application** class looks like this :

```
package application;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import static org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But for a very weird reason the **Starter** class is still getting initialized.

Can anyone explain why the `ComponentScan excludeFilters` is not excluding my `Starter` class ?

Comment: Either I'm missing the main (method) in SimpleTestConfig, or you do not explained well where do you want to exclude from

Comment: Replace `@SpringBootApplication` with `@Configuration` on you `SimpleTestConfig` class. And also hope it in your src/main folder, if you are creating a test purpose configuration(in src/test folder), use `@TestConfiguration` annotation instead.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550494/componentscan-excludefilters-not-working-in-spring-4-0-6-release

Comment: Rwlated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Each component scan does filtering individually. While you exclude `Starter.class` from `SimpleTestConfig`, `SimpleTestConfig` initializes `Application`, which does it's own `@ComponentScan` without excluding `Starter`.
The clean way of using ComponentScan is for each ComponentScan to scan separate packages, that way each filter works fine. When 2 separate ComponentScans scan the same package (as in your tests), this does not work.

One way to trick this is to provide a mock `Starter` bean:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

public class SimpleTest {
    @MockBean
    private Starter myTestBean;
    ...
}
```

Spring will use that mock instead of the real class, thus the `@PostConstruct` method will not be called.

Other common solutions:

- Do not directly use `Application.class` in any unit test
- Use Spring profile and annotations such as `@Profile("!TEST")` on the `Starter` class
- Use a spring Boot `@ConditionalOn...` annotation on the `Starter` class

Comment: I am very appreciate you answer, but if that’s right, so why is the filter designed in Spring? , what’s is purpose?

Comment: The purpose is anything you want it to use for. It is very useful when a testConfig does a componentScan without also scanning another config that has it's own componentScan for similar packages (like Application in your case).

Comment: another option is to use `@TypeExcludeFilters` annotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59815772/355438

Comment: @Lu55: Feel free to modify my answer to include that option.

Answer (score 3):

You can define custom component scan filter for excluding it.

Example code will be like:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters=@Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.wyn.applications.starter.Starter*"))
public class SimpleTestConfig {

}
```

This works for me.

For further reading go to this [blog](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-component-scan-include-and-exclude-filter-example).