# How to override Spring Bean in integration test with custom bean definition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I would like to reuse Spring production context configuration, but replace a few beans with another ones. If I would like to override them with a mock, I would use `@MockBean`, which does exactly what I need (overrides bean), but does not allow me to configure a new bean myselves.

I know there is another way to use `@ContextConfiguration` but it seems too verbose  to me.

Thanks.

Comment: @MockBean is for testing, not for application code.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about integration testing (unit tests where spring context is being loaded)

Comment: There is no simple way to override bean except to define a new one with the same type and mark it as `@Primary`. `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` can't guarantee what bean will be overridden because of the unpredictable configuration order. Alternative approach would be to exclude production beans from the context (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134123/355438)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [@SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) - then bean can be stubbed for specific cases (like in the case of `@MockBean`), but otherwise real bean will be used.

Also, if you actually need to define custom bean definition for tests, then combination of [@Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) / [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) / [@ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) can be used for this purpose.

For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, ApplicationConfig.class})
public class ApplicatonTest {
    @Profile("test")
    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public SomeBean testBeanDefinition() {
            SomeBean testBean = new SomeBean();
            // configure SomeBean for test
            return testBean;
        }
    }
    // tests
}
```

Comment: 1) Do I have to mark production beans from ApplicationConfig as `!test`? 2) Don't you think there should be a simplier solution?

Comment: 1) No, there is no need to mark prod beans as `!test`. Profiles overriding takes place. 2) Unfortunately, I don't know simpler way. Usually, when `@MockBean` is not enough, `@SpyBean` solves my needs. Sometimes I had to stub `@SpyBean` to return another `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean` (and so on recursively). But if your use case is really to have custom bean configuration for tests, then `@Configuration` with `@Primary`  is the last resort, as far as I know.

Comment: Does it work even if I already have @Primary bean in production config?

Comment: If exactly one `primary` bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value.

Comment: yea, but what if I already have primary bean? e.g. Almost all my services uses default http client (which I marked `@Primary`), and some of them uses another http-client-with-proxy (with `@Qualifier`). And I what to ovverride that primary http client in unit test.

Comment: I think [@Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) on @Bean in your test config can help. Just set highest precedence for your test bean, e.g. `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`.

Comment: With this solution, I still get "Failed to load ApplicationContext" because "Cannot register bean definition (...) for bean (...) There is already [Generic bean: class (...) defined in file (...)". So much magic...

Comment: @OleksiiZghurskyi Same issue as DanielM, but the `Order` does not help :(

Comment: Bean overriding feature is disabled by default. You need to enable this feature by switching on an application property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` in your test application properties.